# How to setup my environment variables with zsh on the Mac (El Capitan)

Tags: android, macos, environment-variables, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to add my system environments to my Mac (using El Capitan) and using zsh.

I have echo the following in the terminal and get the following:

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh

echo $0
-zsh

echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

How would I change the system environment variables to the following - as I'm a little unsure of how this is done with zsh?

I want to add the following :

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/opt/ant
export MAVEN_HOME=/usr/local/opt/maven
export GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/opt/gradle
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your text in ~/.zshrc

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/opt/ant
export MAVEN_HOME=/usr/local/opt/maven
export GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/opt/gradle
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
```